# Relation between independent sets and covers

Tags: graph-theory

I want to talk about two independent sets and two covers.

Independent sets:
**(1)** Independent set (or more precisely Independent Vertex Set)
**(2)** Matchings (or more precisely Independent Edge Set)

Covers:
**(1)** Vertex covers
**(2)** Edge covers

I came across following two facts about vertex covers and independent sets, noted in various texts and even on wikipedia:

1. Vertex cover and independent sets are complement of each other.
2. End points of maximal matching is a vertex cover.

But I did not come across the equivalents of above for edge covers and matchings.
 **[1]** Isnt edge cover and matching are complement of each other? (I tried some graphs and now strongly feel yes, but need confirmation. Didnt find any text saying that.)
**[2]** I was not able come up with the edge cover-independent set equivalent for fact 2, i.e. "End points of maximal matching is a vertex cover" what can it be? Or there is none?

Comment: For [1], consider a $K_2$, i.e. two vertices sharing an edge $e$.  The edge $e$ is a matching, but its complement (the empty set) is not an edge  cover.   I don't about any special properties for [2], except the simple statement that a perfect matching is an edge cover.

Comment: Thanks for proving [1] wrong. I know [2] stated by you. I made mistake in asking fact 2 equivalent for edge cover and matching. Fact 2 links vertex cover and matching. So, I was to ask for link between edge cover and independent set. Not the edge cover and matching...One such link is, for complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$, size of minimum edge cover = size of largest independent set = $max(m,n)$. But is there any link between edge cover and independent set of any graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a (minimal) edge cover is at least the size of a maximal independed set, because no edge can cover more than one vertex of such a set.

Comment: **(1)** why is there "at least"? In what case minimal edge cover will have number of edges more than the number of vertices in the maximal independent set? **(2)** I believe we cannot add "minimal" to vertex cover equivalent, right? That is, it cannot be: "End points of maximal matching is a minimal vertex cover". Minimal vertex cover will always be smaller than the vertex cover obtained from the set of end points of maximal matchings, right?

Comment: @anir (1) For instance, in $K_3$  a minimal edge cover has $2$ edges, whereas a maximal independent vertex set has $1$ vertex. (2) Writing (minimal) I meant that since a size of any edge cover is at least a size of a maximal independent set this holds for minimal edge covers too. "End points of maximal matching is a minimal vertex cover". Sometimes this is true, for instance, for the same graph $K_3$.

Comment: I guess, similar to what you said "...because no edge can cover more than one vertex of such a set....", we can also say "no vertex can cover more than one edge of maximal matching". To prove "equals" part of "at least" (that is ">="), we can consider graph with single edge, in which number edges in minimal edge cover = number of vertices in maximal independent set = number of edges in maximal matching = number of vertices in minimal vertex cover = 1. Right?(Super thanks to comment and resolve my stupid doubt even after so many years and very sorry for not checking out answer for so long time)

Comment: @anir Right.......